# Installation of Windows Kernel Mode driver requires network access?

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-kernel

I'm trying to get a certificate for myself, paying $200 to get it. Before I go buy it, does anybody know if installation of a kernel mode driver (that requires the code to be signed) has to have network access, how does it verify the authenticity? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network access is not needed. The authenticity is verified by checking the digital signatures and certificates themselves. Network access is only used to update certificate revocation lists (in case any certificates have been revoked), and an operation won't fail just because the CRL couldn't be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to buy a certificate to test Windows drivers, you can turn on Test-Signing mode. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547660(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.